# Working with lists of lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

New to [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog), trying to get my head around dealing with lists of lists recursively.

Say I have a list:

```
prices([20, 20, 40]).
```

And another list (of lists):

```
items([ [12, 14, 23],[8, 16, 22],[18, 12, 14] ]).
```

I want to append an element from prices to each list in items:

```
items([ [12, 14, 23, 20],[8, 16, 22, 20],[18, 12, 14, 40] ]).
```

I'm having trouble with working through both a single list and a list of lists at the same time.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried ? there is a typo : items([[12, 14, 23],[8, 16, 22],[18, 12, 14] **]** ).

Comment: Not really. It's similar to a problem that I missed in the past semester.

Comment: Joel - thanks for catching the typo. I don't have access to the directory my code is in at the moment, but I was basically trying to append the head of the the single list to the head of the list of lists.

Answer (score 4):

It's not too difficult if you sort it out in its appropriate pieces. In prolog, a list is a list until you need to do something with an element.

```
item_prices(ItemPrices) :-
    prices(Prices),
    items(ItemLists),
    item_prices(ItemLists, Prices, [], ItemPrices), !.
item_prices([ItemList|ItemLists], [Price|Prices], SoFar, ItemPrices) :-
    append(ItemList, [Price], ItemPrice),  % Assumes the items are lists, price is not
    item_prices(ItemLists, Prices, [ItemPrice|SoFar], ItemPrices).
item_prices(_, _, ItemPrices, ItemPrices).
```

Then you'd just call:

```
item_prices(ItemPrices).
```

To give:

```
ItemPrices = [[18,12,14,40],[8,16,22,20],[12,14,23,20]]
```

Comment: seems pointless to use an accumulator, actually reversing the original order

Comment: @CapelliC yes in this case you are right. It was the first approach that popped into my mind. You've got it covered in your answer already (+1) so I won't edit.

Comment: @mbratch ... hmm, it should have been "4-dimensional solver for the 8-queens problem".  less ambiguous this way. :) (4D: 2 rows, 2 columns).

Answer (score 2):

any time you have difficulty in dealing with too much stuff at the same time, see if you can [separate your concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and deal with each separately, through an auxiliary predicate.

For instance here you could define `add_to_end( Element, List, Newlist)` and use it in your main predicate.

```
add_to_end( E, [], R):- R = ... .
add_to_end( E, [A|B], R):- R=[A|X], add_to_end( E, B, ...).
```

When you've mastered the basics of the language, do see what's there in the library; chances are there's already a predicate that lets you append two lists, which you could use somehow instead of writing your own specialized version of it. After all, `add_to_end( E, L, R) == append_two_lists(L, [E], ...)`.

Comment: Great advice for any problem and any language!

Answer (score 2):

this is a variation on mbratch answer

```
item_prices(ItemPrices) :-
    prices(Prices),
    items(ItemLists),
    item_prices(ItemLists, Prices, ItemPrices), !.
item_prices([ItemList|ItemLists], [Price|Prices], [ItemPrice|ItemPrices]) :-
    append(ItemList, [Price], ItemPrice),  % Assumes the items are lists, price is not
    item_prices(ItemLists, Prices, ItemPrices).
item_prices([], [], []).
```

without an accumulator, we avoid to reverse the order.

Here is a solution, using maplist/3, handy when you must perform the same operation among matched lists elements:

```
items_updated(Us) :-
    items(Is),
    prices(Ps),
    maplist(append_, Is, Ps, Us).
append_(Is, P, R) :- append(Is, [P], R).
```